# ¿Cómo puedo hacer este ej. de diccionarios de Python?

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios, ordenamiento, tuplas

Se tiene una lista "Info" que contiene la fecha de nacimiento y defunción de distintos escritores, como muestra el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Info=[[1914, 1999],[1890, 1979],[1889,1957],[1899,1986],[1874,1938],[1878,1937],[1886,1950],
[1914,1998],[1914,1984]]
```

Utilizando esta lista, se creó un diccionario que contiene la fecha de nacimiento y defunción de grandes escritores, como muestra el siguiente ejemplo:

```
{('Adolfo', 'Bioy Casares'):Info[0],('Victoria','Ocampo'):Info[1],('Gabriela', 'Mistral'):Info[2],('Jorge Luis','Borges'):Info[3],('Leopoldo','Lugones'):Info[4],('Horacio','Quiroga'):Info[5],
('Baldomero', 'Fernández Moreno'):Info[6],('Octavio','Paz'):Info[7],('Julio','Cortazar'):Info[8]}
```

Se desea realizar tres funciones.

a) Una función que tome como entrada el diccionario y devuelva una lista de los escritores (nombre y apellido) ordenada alfabéticamente  según el apellido.

b) Una función que tome como entrada solamente la lista Info, de forma tal que el diccionario ahora incluya la edad en la que murieron los escritores.

c) Una función que tome como entrada el diccionario y devuelva una lista de los escritores (nombre y apellido) ordenada alfabéticamente según la edad.

El punto 1a ya lo he hecho de la siguiente forma:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import json

def count(num_list):
    count_dict = {}
    for num in num_list:
        count_dict[num] = num_list.count(num)
    return dict(sorted(count_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]))

Info = [[1914, 1999], [1890, 1979], [1889, 1957], [1899, 1986], [1874, 1938], [1878, 1937], [1886, 1950],
            [1914, 1998], [1914, 1984]]


Escritores = {('Adolfo', 'Bioy Casares'): (Info[0]), ('Victoria', 'Ocampo'): Info[1],
                  ('Gabriela', 'Mistral'): Info[2], ('Jorge Luis', 'Borges'): Info[3], ('Leopoldo', 'Lugones'): Info[4],
                  ('Horacio', 'Quiroga'): Info[5],
                  ('Baldomero', 'Fernández Moreno'): Info[6], ('Octavio', 'Paz'): Info[7],
                  ('Julio', 'Cortazar'): Info[8]}

l2 = sorted(Escritores, key=itemgetter(1, 0))
print(l2)
```

---

Ahora no me sale realizar el punto 1b y 1c. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para ordenar los nombres y apellidos junto con las edades ordenadas?

Comment: Puedes recorrer el diccionario añadiendo a cada una de las listas donde están los años un elemento más, la resta de esos años. Una vez tienes una lista así (lo que te resolvería el punto b) sería sencillo hacer el punto c, de forma muy similar a como ya hiciste el a

Comment: como seria eso no lo entiendo?

Comment: ¿para qué importas el módulo json si no lo usas? ¿para qué defines la función `count()`? No parece jugar ningún papel en lo que va después y tampoco parece estar relacionada con ninguna de las cosas que te pide el ejercicio

Answer (score 0):

Para hallar la edad de los escritores es muy sencillo, solo deberás recorrer la información y restar la fecha de muerte con su nacimiento.
Además para ya tener los cambios en el diccionario habrá que agregarlo

```
def edad(info):
     i=0
     for n,m in info:
          edad = m-n
          info[i].append(edad)
          i+=1
     return info
```

Para obtener el nombre completo de un escritor solo habrá que acceder a las tuplas y juntar sus valores

```
def fullName(dic):
     for names in dic:
          FullName = f'{names[0]} {names[1]}'
          print(FullName)
```

Esto irá imprimiendo los nombres de cada escritor, pero podemos almacenarlos en un array y devolver todo, aparte se dice que deberá estar ordenado según la edad

**añadimos  el array y ordenamos según la edad**

```
def fullName(dic):
     allNames =[]
     for names in dic:
          FullName = f'{names[0]} {names[1]}'
          allNames.append(FullName)
     return sorted(allNames, key= lambda x:x[3])
```

Para ordenarlo hacemos uso de la función  sorted como lo hiciste en tu codigo, así que no necesidad de explicar.